# Store & pass data as an array from a function to another function or code

Tags: arrays, c, function

I encountered a problem when I try to pass my data which I stored in the function to a new code. when the output runs for the loop which should output a list of data I entered earlier. It just prints a random number. What is going on

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f_arrPlate (int n)
{
    int plate[10];
    printf ("\nPlate = ");
    scanf("%d",&plate[n]);
    printf("%d_Number = %d\n",n,plate[n]);

    }

int main ()
{
    int n,plate[10];
    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
        f_arrPlate(n);
        }

    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
         printf("%d_Number = %d\n",n,plate[n]);




    }
}
```

Comment: The program does not make a sense.

Answer (score -1):

You are modifying the local `plate` in the function `f_arrPlate` instead of `plate` in the function `main`. The `plate` in `f_arrPlate` is invalidated on returning from the function.

You should either pass the array to modify as an argument or make the array global.

Also note that array indice in C start from 0, not 1. Therefore you should make offset or allocate one more element to avoid out-of-range access.

Fix with additional argument and element:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f_arrPlate (int* plate, int n)
{
    printf ("\nPlate = ");
    scanf("%d",&plate[n]);
    printf("%d_Number = %d\n",n,plate[n]);

    }

int main ()
{
    int n,plate[11];
    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
        f_arrPlate(plate,n);
        }

    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
         printf("%d_Number = %d\n",n,plate[n]);




    }
}
```

Fix with global variable and offset:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int plate[10];

int f_arrPlate (int n)
{
    printf ("\nPlate = ");
    scanf("%d",&plate[n-1]);
    printf("%d_Number = %d\n",n,plate[n-1]);

    }

int main ()
{
    int n;
    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
        f_arrPlate(n);
        }

    for (n=1;n<=10;n++){
         printf("%d_Number = %d\n",n,plate[n-1]);




    }
}
```